# MySQL: how to change selected value

Tags: mysql

I'm running a stored procedure to insert values in my shipin table. My question is, my selected field AccountID needs to have a different value than what is returned.

For example, if it returns a value of 16, it needs to insert 191 in my shipin table. If it returns a value of 1, it needs to insert 125 in my shipin table. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO `timestone`.`shipin`
 (`REFERENCE_1`,
  `REFERENCE_2`,
  `date_loaded`,
  `location`)
SELECT
  `shipinimport`.`SubjectKey`, --Reference 1
  `shipinimport`.`AccountID`, --Reference 2
  Now(), --DateLoaded
  'DPI'--location
FROM `dpi_timestone`.`shipinimport`;
```

Edit:

So I'm trying to insert the case expression, but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

```
INSERT INTO `timestone`.`shipin`
 (`REFERENCE_1`,
  `REFERENCE_2`,
  `date_loaded`,
  `location`)
SELECT
  `shipinimport`.`SubjectKey`, --Reference 1
  `shipinimport`.`AccountID`, --Reference 2
  Now(), --DateLoaded
  'DPI'--location
Case AccountID
  When 16 Then 191
  When 1 Then 125
End
FROM `dpi_timestone`.`shipinimport`;
```

Comment: You can use a `CASE` expression like this `CASE AccountID WHEN 16 THEN 191 WHEN 1 THEN 125 WHEN ?? THEN ??? ... END`

Comment: Is there a pattern? what's the relation between 16 & 191 and 1 & 125?? If there's a relation then we can try to implement that -else if these are two specific cases then you can go with @GiorgosBetsos 's suggestion

Comment: No relation. Just two different systems that have different values for the same account. And I'm still pretty new to mysql which means I'm still struggling with syntax. Can I put the expression in my existing select?

Comment: If I was you I would create a mapping table

Comment: If I had a lot of records I probably would, but I only have a few, so the case expressions seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might want a reference, this ended up working for me to return the results.

```
    INSERT INTO `timestone`.`shipin`
     (`REFERENCE_1`,
      `REFERENCE_2`,
      `date_loaded`,
      `location`)
    SELECT
      `shipinimport`.`SubjectKey`, --Reference 1
      `shipinimport`.`AccountID`, --Reference 2
      Now(), --DateLoaded
      'DPI'--location
    FROM `dpi_timestone`.`shipinimport`;
    Select Case AccountID
      When 16 Then 191
      When 1 Then 125
    End
    FROM `dpi_timestone`.`shipinimport`;
```